# Neural network for rainfall forecasting

Tags: forecasting, neural-networks

I'm new to machine learning, and I have been trying to figure out how to apply neural network to rainfall forecasting. I have found resource related to my query, but I seem to still be a bit lost. I think a basic explanation without too much detail would help.

Let's say I have 10 climate features values for each month over a few years, and I want to predict rainfall for new month. How I can apply neural network to this  problem is what I am trying to find out. How can I give input in this because we have 10(features) * 12 months * 10 years.

Comment: i want to apply ann

Comment: What resources have you found? Why don't you list them? How did you decide on using a Neural Network? I think your question's too vague and broad.

Answer (score 1):

One paper you definitely ought to read is:

Williams, P. M., "Modelling Seasonality and Trends in Daily Rainfall Data", ADVANCES IN NEURAL INFORMATION PROCESSING SYSTEMS, 1998, volume 10, pages 985-991
MORGAN KAUFMANN PUBLISHERS, ISSN 1049-5258.

For representing the input, I would suggest you read a good book on neural network techniques before you begin.  The book by Chris Bishop on "Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition" is excellent, it focusses mainly on pattern recognition, but most of the issues apply equally to regression problems.

Comment: Do you mean Chris Bishop's book *Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition*?

Comment: yes, that is the one, I've edited my answer, thanks.